# Changing array in another class programmatically

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I am programmatically presenting a view controller (SavedGames.swift -> OnePlayer.swift), and I cannot figure out how to change the array in the view controller I am presenting (OnePlayer.swift) in the original controller (SavedGames.swift).  I want to change tableData in OnePlayer in the block of code in SavedGames.swift..  Hope that makes sense

SavedGames.swift:

```
        if let resultController = storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("OnePlayer") as? OnePlayer {
            presentViewController(resultController, animated: true, completion: nil)

            //in OnePlayer, set tableData to this tableData: [String] = ["one", "two", "three"]
        }
```

OnePlayer.swift:

```
var tableData: [String] = ["zero", "zero", "zero"]
```

Comment: I basically want to override OnePlayer tableData with the tableData array in SavedGames upon load, from the SavedGames class.

Comment: i am ready to help you. i know the logic. but you can write the code for that... in swift.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this

```
    if let resultController = storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("OnePlayer") as? OnePlayer {
          resultController.tableData = ["zero", "zero", "zero"]
          presentViewController(resultController, animated: true, completion: nil)

            //in OnePlayer, set tableData to this tableData: [String] = ["one", "two", "three"]
        }
```

Comment: If both tableData are of same type, then resultController.tableData = self.tableData

Comment: @JoshO'Connor, Accept the answer so that it will help others as the right answer.